# how to make `ConfirmChoice`function cancel from `main if it is false?

Tags: c++

I need to make`ConfirmChoice` cancel  from the main function before it starts the rest of the code. I have tried a lot and can not figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const char CASH = 'C';
const char CREDIT = 'D';
const char NOSEBLEED = 'N';
const char BOX_SEAT = 'B';
const char FIFTY_YARD_LINE = 'F';
const char STUDENT_SECTION = 'S';
const float NOSEBLEED_PRICE = 43.42;
const float BOX_SEAT_PRICE = 353.85;
const float FIFTY_YARD_LINE_PRICE = 94.05;
const float STUDENT_SECTION_PRICE = 19.99;

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Function: ConfirmChoice
// Purpose:  Confirms the users ticket purchase before processing payment
// Parameters:  TicketType - The type of ticket selected
// Returns:  true if the user confirms the selection, false otherwise
//--------------------------------------------------------------
bool ConfirmChoice(const char TicketType)
{
   char Choice;
   bool Confirmed;

   // Print out their selection
   cout << "\nYou have chosen to purchase ";
   cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
   switch (TicketType)
   {
   case NOSEBLEED:
      cout << "Nosebleed ticket(s) at a price of $";
      cout << NOSEBLEED_PRICE << ".\n";
      break;
   case BOX_SEAT:
      cout << "Box Seat ticket(s) at a price of $";
      cout << BOX_SEAT_PRICE << ".\n";
      break;
   case FIFTY_YARD_LINE:
      cout << "Ticket(s) on the 50 yard line at a price of $";
      cout << FIFTY_YARD_LINE_PRICE << ".\n";
      break;
   case STUDENT_SECTION:
      cout << "Ticket(s) in the Student Section at a price of $";
      cout << STUDENT_SECTION_PRICE << ".\n";
      break;
   }

   // Confirm the selection
   cout << "Do you wish to confirm your purchase? Enter Y or N: ";
   cin >> Choice;
   Choice = toupper(Choice);
   while (Choice != 'Y' && Choice != 'N')
   {
      cout << "Invalid selection.  Please enter either Y or N: ";
      cin >> Choice;
      Choice = toupper(Choice);
   }
   Confirmed = (Choice == 'Y');

   // Check confirmation        
   if (Confirmed)
      cout << "You have confirmed your choice.\n" << endl;
   else
      cout << "You not confirmed your choice.\n" << endl;
   return (Confirmed);
}

//-------------------------------------------
// Function: CalculateChange
// Purpose:  To output the change due
// Parameters:  ChangeDue - The amount of change needed 
// Returns:  Nothing
//-------------------------------------------
void CalculateChange(const float ChangeDue)
{
   int Change = 0;
   int Dollars = 0;
   int Quarters = 0;
   int Dimes = 0;
   int Nickels = 0;
   int Pennies = 0;

   // Compute change  
   Change = ChangeDue * 100;
   Dollars = Change / 100;
   Change = Change % 100;
   Quarters = Change / 25;
   Change = Change % 25;
   Dimes = Change / 10;
   Change = Change % 10;
   Nickels = Change / 5;
   Pennies = Change % 5;

   // Print out change
   cout << "Your change is \n\t";
   cout << Dollars << " Dollars\n\t";
   cout << Quarters << " Quarters\n\t";
   cout << Dimes << " Dimes\n\t";
   cout << Nickels << " Nickels\n\t";
   cout << Pennies << " Pennies\n";
}

 int main()
{   
   // Prints my name and UAID
        cout <<"\n\nName: Ivory Newbern\n";
        cout << "UAID: 010563918\n";

   // Declarations 

   char TChoice ;       // Ticket type: Nosebleed, box seats etc.. 
   char PChoice = GetPaymentType();     // Payment choice: cash or credit card
   bool Confirmed ;     // Did the user confirm the selection
   float Cost ;         // The cost of the ticket puchased
   float ChangeDue;     // The amount of change owed (for cash purchases)



   // Get the choice of payment type
    PChoice;

   // Get the choice of ticket type
    GetTicketType( TChoice);
   // Confirm the selection
    ConfirmChoice( TChoice);

    // If they confirm the purchase


      // Calls functions to figure out the price of ticket purchase(s) 

           if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
               Cost = CalculateCost(BOX_SEAT_PRICE);
           if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
               Cost = CalculateCost(NOSEBLEED_PRICE);
           if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
               Cost = CalculateCost(STUDENT_SECTION_PRICE);
           if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
               Cost = CalculateCost(FIFTY_YARD_LINE_PRICE);

      // Handles the payment 

           if( PChoice == 'C');
                PayWithCash(Cost,ChangeDue) , CalculateChange(ChangeDue);
           if( PChoice == 'D')
                PayWithCredit(Cost);

       // Say goodbye to the customer
           if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
           cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'BOX_SEAT' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
           if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
              cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'NOSEBLEED' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl; 
           if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
              cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'STUDENT_SECTION' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
           if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
                cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'FIFTY_YARD_LINE' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;


   // Else

      // Cancel the purchase 
    system ("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "cancel from main"? If you want to whole program to quit you can use [exit(int)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) from cstdlib.

Comment: Well I need the whole program to cancel only if ( ConfirmChoice( TChoice) =='N' without changing ConfirmChoice(const char TicketType)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
if( ConfirmChoice( TChoice));

       {

               if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
                   Cost = CalculateCost(BOX_SEAT_PRICE);
               if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
                   Cost = CalculateCost(NOSEBLEED_PRICE);
               if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
                   Cost = CalculateCost(STUDENT_SECTION_PRICE);
               if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
                   Cost = CalculateCost(FIFTY_YARD_LINE_PRICE);

          // Handles the payment 

               if( PChoice == 'C');
                    PayWithCash(Cost,ChangeDue) , CalculateChange(ChangeDue);
               if( PChoice == 'D')
                    PayWithCredit(Cost);

           // Say goodbye to the customer
               if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
               cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'BOX_SEAT' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
               if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
                  cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'NOSEBLEED' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl; 
               if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
                  cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'STUDENT_SECTION' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
               if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
                    cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'FIFTY_YARD_LINE' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;

    }
      else
    {
        system ("PAUSE");
       return 0;
    }<br/>
```

for optimized purpose:
here `else` part not required, u can simply remove the `else` part,like this:

```
if( ConfirmChoice( TChoice));

           {

                   if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
                       Cost = CalculateCost(BOX_SEAT_PRICE);
                   if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
                       Cost = CalculateCost(NOSEBLEED_PRICE);
                   if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
                       Cost = CalculateCost(STUDENT_SECTION_PRICE);
                   if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
                       Cost = CalculateCost(FIFTY_YARD_LINE_PRICE);

              // Handles the payment 

                   if( PChoice == 'C');
                        PayWithCash(Cost,ChangeDue) , CalculateChange(ChangeDue);
                   if( PChoice == 'D')
                        PayWithCredit(Cost);

               // Say goodbye to the customer
                   if (TChoice == BOX_SEAT)
                   cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'BOX_SEAT' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
                   if (TChoice == NOSEBLEED)
                      cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'NOSEBLEED' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl; 
                   if (TChoice == STUDENT_SECTION)
                      cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'STUDENT_SECTION' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;
                   if (TChoice == FIFTY_YARD_LINE)
                        cout << "Thank you for the purchase of your 'FIFTY_YARD_LINE' tickets ,have a nice day!" << endl;

        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work what I need this to do is "cancel the purchasing process before the payment processing starts"

Comment: Just remove the whole `else` branch of the if and you're good. "If the choice is positive, do something and quit, otherwise do nothing and quit." In your example code you just ignored the return value of ConfirmChoice, here it is checked and the program reacts accordingly.